# Create an Azure VM with a non-Premium SSD as OS disk with Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I want to create an Azure VM with a non-Premium SSD as OS disk to save costs. I must use the CLI. I did not find a parameter for `az vm create` where I could specify the SKU of the OS disk. When I try to create the disk manually it succeeds, but after that when I try to attach the disk to a new VM with `--attach-os-disk` I cannot use the `--admin-username` and `--admin-password` any more that I need for initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the --storage-sku parameter to choose your storage type:

> --storage-sku The SKU of the storage account with which to persist VM. Use a singular sku that would be applied across all disks, or specify
> individual disks. Usage: [--storage-sku SKU | --storage-sku ID=SKU
> ID=SKU ID=SKU...], where each ID is "os" or a 0-indexed lun. Allowed
> values: Standard_LRS, Premium_LRS, StandardSSD_LRS, UltraSSD_LRS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-create

Comment: I came across that flag, but I thought that was only for unmanaged disks